# How to get a downloadable file from a readableStream response in a fetch request

Tags: reactjs, csv, download, stream, rails-api

I have a react app that sends a POST request to my rails API. I want my API endpoint to generate a csv file and then to send back that file to the react app. I want then the browser to download of the csv file for the end user.

Here's how the endpoint looks like :

```
  def generate
      // next line builds the csv in tmp directory
      period_recap_csv = period_recap.build_csv
       // next line is supposed to send back the csv as response
      send_file Rails.root.join(period_recap.filepath), filename: period_recap.filename, type: 'text/csv'
    end
```

On the front end side here's how my request looks like :

```
export function generateCsvRequest(startDate, endDate) {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/billing/finance-recaps/generate", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Authorisation: `Token token=${authToken}`,
      'Accept': 'text/csv',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Key-Inflection': 'camel',
    },
    //make sure to serialize your JSON body
    body: JSON.stringify({
      start_date: startDate,
      end_date: endDate
    })
  })
  .then( (response) => {
    console.log('resp', response);
    return response;
  }).then((data) => {
      // what should I do Here with the ReadableStream I get back ??
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

As the response body I get a readableStream :
[image]

What should I do now with that ReadableStream object to launch the download of that CSV file on the end user browser ?

Comment: Found any solution? Have the same problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you use the fetch API, your response object has a bunch of methods to handle the data that you get. The most used is `json()`. If you need to download a file coming from the server what you need is `blob()`, which works the same way as `json()`.

```
response.blob().then(blob => download(blob))
```

There are a lot of npm packages to download files. [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) is one of them. One way that works without dependencies though is by using the `a` tag. Something like that:

```
function download(blob, filename) {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  // the filename you want
  a.download = filename;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Anyway, using a dependency would cover more edge cases, and it's usually more compatible. I hope that can be useful

If you want to show the pdf in another tab instead of downloading it, you would use `window.open` and pass the URL generated by `window.URL.createObjectURL`.

```
function showInOtherTab(blob) {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: Good solution. How would you go about opening the blob (say pdf file) in a new window instead of downloading it?

Comment: Hi Vlad, I updated my post with the answer to your question

Comment: Perfect, I came to the same answer after experimenting a bit

Comment: Perfect and simple solution ✅

Answer (score 6):

If the end point a stream, one solution is retrieve the whole file then to save it.

> *Disclaimer: the solution I offer below involve loading a whole pdf file in memory and avoid opening a new window tab to download the file (using [downloadjs](https://github.com/rndme/download): very useful to rename and save the downloaded data). **If anyone get a solution to avoid loading the whole file in memory before saving it, fell free to share :) :)**.*

Here is the code:

```
import download from 'downloadjs'

fetch(...)
  .then(response => {
    //buffer to fill with all data from server
    let pdfContentBuffer = new Int8Array();

    // response.body is a readableStream 
    const reader = response.body.getReader();

    //function to retreive the next chunk from the stream
    function handleChunk({ done, chunk })  {
      if (done) {
        //everything has been loaded, call `download()` to save gthe file as pdf and name it "my-file.pdf"
        download(pdfContentBuffer, `my-file.pdf`, 'application/pdf')
        return;
      }

      // concat already loaded data with the loaded chunk
      pdfContentBuffer = Int8Array.from([...pdfContentBuffer, ...chunk]);

      // retreive next chunk
      reader.read().then(handleChunk);
    }

    //retreive first chunk
    reader.read().then(handleChunk)
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

I share it hoping this will help others.